# iOS Facebook SDK 4 FBSDKShareDialog

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have some trouble when I try to implement `FBSDKShareDialog` to perform facebook sharing via my app. If official fb app is installed it shows blank dialog (where user allows to type some text etc). If user doesn't have fb app it shows correct info but `FBSDKSharingDelegate` methods doesn't work. (It doesn't work even when user has fb application)

```
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
{
    NSLog(@"complete");
}
- (void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer
{
    NSLog(@"did cancel");
}

- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

It's never called even when I cancel or share via FB application. 
My code is:

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
    content.contentTitle = _place.title;
    content.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:_place.logoUrl];
    content.contentDescription = _place.info;
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:_viewController withContent:content delegate:self];
```

I have a delegate inside `@interface` declaration.

```
@interface FacebookHandler () < FBSDKSharingDelegate >

@end
```

My app delegate has

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

Where I was wrong? And is it good idea to post some image and title via `FBSDKShareLinkContent`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already fixed this issue. The problem was that I've delegate to file inherited from NSObject, which can't be a delegate

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `[FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:self]` from the main thread?